# dynamic ecto select with several fragment

Tags: elixir, ecto

trying to build this dynamically

```
> from u in Table, 
  select: [ 
     u.field1, 
     u.field2, %{ 
       "1" => fragment("some fragment"), 
       "2" => fragment("some fragment "), 
       .. 
       "n" => fragment("some fragment"), 
      }
 ]
```

is there any way to modify the select expression afterwards to add elements in the map ?

otherwise build the list beforehand but with the fragment it does not work outside of the from function

is macro the only way ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is currently impossible in ecto 2.1

it will be available on a later versions probably through the dynamic macro